# Assistance on x86 Assembler running on Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I am currently learning a bit of Assembler on Linux and I need your advice.
Here is the small program:

```
.section .data
  zahlen:
   .float 12,44,5,143,223,55,0

.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl zahlen (,%edi,4), %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx

 begin_loop:
   cmpl $0, %eax
   je prog_end
   incl %edi
   movl zahlen (,%edi,4), %eax
   cmpl %ebx, %eax
   jle begin_loop
   movl %eax, %ebx
   jmp begin_loop

prog_end:
   movl $1, %eax
   int $0x80
```

The program seems to compiling and running fine.
But I have some unclear questions/behaviors:

1. if I check the return value, which is the highers number in register %ebx, with the command "echo %?" it always return 0. I expect the value 223.
   Any Idea why this happens?
2. I checked with DDD and gdb compiling with debugging option. So i saw that the program runs the correct steps.
   But if i want to exam the register with command ie. "i r eax" it only shows me the address i believe, not the value. Same on DDD. I see only registers rax rbx and so on.
   Here i need some advise to get on the right track.
   Any Help appreciated.
   Thanks

Comment: `i r eax` or `p $eax` will show you the FP bit-pattern you loaded into EAX, since you used `.float` instead of `.long`.  e.g. `(float)12` is represented by the integer bit-pattern `0x41400000`. https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html .  All your floats are small integers, so the low 8 bits of their mantissas is zero (Unix exit status values are 8-bit).  (You can see this with `x /7xw zahlen` to dump 7 32-bit chunks of memory in hex.)  Also, since this is 32-bit code, you should be building it as 32-bit, not 64-bit. EAX is the low half of RAX in 64-bit mode.

Comment: The reason the program still gets the highest value into EBX is that FP bit patterns increase monotonically with magnitude, because of the biased exponent.  And yours are all non-negative, so the sign/magnitude vs. 2's complement issue doesn't come up.  And they're non-NaN so there aren't any compares that should be unordered.

Comment: You are comparing the bits of float numbers. Since those are integer numbers, they'll have a few bit set in their mantissa. Which means their lower byte is most likely zero. The return code is only 8-bit wide, so you always get zero. Use `.long`/`.int` (or whatever GAS uses) for numbers compared with integer instructions. You are also including the 0 element in the check, which you may want to avoid for other functions (e.g. min).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "main" registers `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, etc. are all designed to work with integers only. A [float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is a shorthand term that typically refers to a very specific data format (namely, the IEEE-754 binary32 standard), for which your CPU has dedicated registers and hardware to work with. As you saw, you are allowed to load them into integer registers as-is, but the value isn't going to convert itself like it would in a high-level, dynamically-typed language.  Your code loaded the raw bit pattern instead, which likely is not at all what you intended.

This is because assembly has no type safety or runtime type-checking. The CPU has no knowledge of what type you declared your data as in your program. So when loading from memory into `eax` the CPU assumes that the data is a 32-bit integer, even if you declared it in your source code as something else.

If you're curious as to what a `float` actually looks like you can check this out: [Floating Point to Hex Calculator](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/)

Answer (score 0):

Switching from float to long solved the problem. Think mistake by myself. Also compiling and linking as 32bit shows the right registers in the debugger.